# Pandas read_json script that used to work now produces an error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that up until recently worked fine, but is now producing an error.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Set the url to given endpoint
url = "https://SomeURL/SomeEndpoint"
print('URL set')

# Connect to endpoint with credentials and put results in dictionary
URLresponse = requests.get(url,auth=("SomeUser", "SomePassword"), verify=True)
print('connection to endpoint')

# Load the response as proper JSON into a var
rawdata = (URLresponse.content)
print(type(rawdata))
print('populating variable')

# print(rawdata)

# Load the var into a dataframe
df = pd.read_json(rawdata) 
print('load variable into df')

print(df)
```

This used to work fine but now it is producing an error as following:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 901, in get_handle
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

How can I go ahead to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `df = pd.read_json(rawdata)` to `df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(rawdata.decode('utf-8')))`

You will need to include `import io` earlier in your file as well.